# Using \settabs in a macro

Tags: tables, plain-tex

In plain TeX, I would like to define a custom column definition and store it in a macro.

```
\def\TableHeader{\settabs\+\indent&\hskip 1.5in&\cr}
```

So I can later define tables

```
\TableHeader
\+&Foo &Text.\cr
\+&Bar &More text.\cr
```

However it doesn't work as a macro

```
Runaway definition?
->\settabs
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning definition of \TableHeader.
<inserted text>
}
<to be read again>
\+
l.3 \def\TableHeader{\settabs\+
                             \indent&\hskip 1.5in&\cr}
?
```

I am looking for the correct way to write such a macro in plain TeX.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro `\+` is declared as `\outer`, so it cannot appear in the replacement text of a macro. Use `\tabalign` instead.

Here's the relevant excerpt from `plain.tex`:

```
601 \def\cleartabs{\global\setbox\tabsyet\null \setbox\tabs\null}
602 \def\settabs{\setbox\tabs\null \futurelet\next\sett@b}
603 \let\+=\relax % in case this file is being read in twice
604 \def\sett@b{\ifx\next\+\def\nxt{\afterassignment\s@tt@b\let\nxt}%
605   \else\let\nxt\s@tcols\fi \let\next\relax \nxt}
606 \def\s@tt@b{\let\nxt\relax \us@false\m@ketabbox}
607 \def\tabalign{\us@true\m@ketabbox} % non-\outer version of \+
608 \outer\def\+{\tabalign}
```

and the corresponding quotation from the TeXbook:

> The macro `\+` has been declared ‘`\outer`’ here, so that TeX will
>   be better able to detect runaway arguments and definitions (see Chapter 20).
>   A non-`\outer` version, called `\tabalign`, has also been provided
>   in case it is necessary to use `\+` in some “inner” place.
>   You can use `\tabalign` just like `\+`, except after `\settabs`.

You seem to be wanting it after `\settabs`, though. In this case the “old trick“ works:

```
\def\TableHeader{\expandafter\settabs\csname+\endcsname\indent&\hskip 1.5in&\cr}

\TableHeader
\+a & b & c\cr

\bye
```